# Limit of Complex Integral is 0

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, complex-integration

How can I show that the $ \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty}$ $\int_{|z|=R} \frac{dz}{(z)(z-3)^2}$ = 0? I have already proved that by ML - inequality, $\Big| \int_{|z|=R} \frac{dz}{(z)(z-3)^2} \Big|$  $\leq \frac{2\pi}{(R-3)^2}.$ Should I use the bound to find the limit of the integral?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right. You simply use the fact that$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{2\pi}{(R-3)^2}=0.$$

Comment: And, of course, that the absolute value of the integral is bounded below by $0$, so it follows by the squeeze theorem (though this statement is a fair bit more obvious).